# Can't access JSON data and print Begin and End only React Native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to access to Begin and End inside JSON data but I can't. It just accesses and prints JSON data.

How can I print the Begin and End in separately FlatList?

Here is my code :

```
manage = date =>  {
 this.setState({status: true})
 this.setState({date:date})
const office_id=this.state.office_id;
const duration=this.state.duration;
  const  url='http://MyIP/api/timeApi';
  axios.post(url,{office_id,date,duration})
  .then(resp => this.setState({
      testArray : JSON.stringify(resp.data),
  }))
  .catch(e)
  {
      alert(e);
  }}

testFunction = () => {
    var x = this.state.testArray;
    return(

        <Text>{x}</Text>
    )

}

<DatePicker
                    date={this.state.date}
                    onDateChange={this.manage.bind(this) } />
```

> in return

```
  { 
        this.state.status ?                 <View>

<FlatList 
  data={this.state.testArray}
     renderItem={this.testFunction}


/>
        </View> : null
    }
```

[and here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxN8o.jpg)

Comment: please put your entire component clearly

Comment: i can't put all my code

Comment: do you want the show on your list only first and last objects ?

Comment: yes i want ....

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this , try to change it based on your code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, FlatList ,Button} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    }
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  manage = () => {
    var x = this.firstAndLast(this.state.data);
    this.setState({
      data : x
    })
  }

   firstAndLast(myArray) {

    var firstItem = myArray[0];
    var lastItem = myArray[myArray.length-1];
    var newArray = [];

    newArray.push(firstItem);
    newArray.push(lastItem);
    
    return newArray;
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          extraData={this.state}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
        <Button title="click" onPress={() => this.manage()} />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```